# In a cross-platform app made with C++ in Visual Studio 2015, is it possible to use NSEvent from Apple's Appkit?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cross-platform, appkit, nsevent

In an application coded with C++ in Visual Studio 2015 and which aims to be cross-platform (currently supports Windows and Linux), is it possible to access `NSEvent` from Apple's Appkit?

Say, as an example, that one would want to retrieve which mouse button has been pressed by a iOS user: would it be possible for a C++ application coded in Visual Studio to retrieve the results of the function `pressedMouseButtons()`, that is part of the `NSEvent` object of thee Appkit?

If so, how should one should call such a function?

Answer (score 0):

You can only call an API that exists on the target platform. So, unless someone has done a port of Appkit, no.

The usual strategy is to wrap platform specific sections with preproccessor conditionals (#ifdef). Your alternative would be to implement emulations of the Appkit functions and data structures you want to use. They don't have to be functional on the non-Apple platform, returning predefined test data should be enough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that I would have to wrap the Apple-specific section of th code with preprocessor conditions. That's what I have been doing for Windows/Linux specific areas of the code already. So in that case, would it be possible to use C++ in Visual Studio 2015 to have a sections of the code calling from the AppKit? I can't find how exactly should I do that since the AppKit requires Objective-C. And by how should I do that, I mean what should I `#include` and how to call a `NSEvent::pressedMouseButtons()` type of function.

Comment: I don't think I understand your goal. Visual C++ targets Windows (and with the help of some extensions Linux and Android). So my assumption was that you were trying to have a common code base for all targets but build and run on the individual platforms.
If you wanted to call AppKit functions like pressedMouseButtons() on non-Apple platforms you would either have to find a ported version of the framework or implement those functions yourself, fully-functional or test stubs.
Have you looked at Cocoa / GNUstep, which is the successor to AppKit and available on Windows and Linux?

Comment: I didn't notice that you have commented again. So, what I am trying to do is simply to write a piece of code in Visual Studio 205, with C++, that when compiled, would generate an application that is able, under Apple Mac, to retrieve values from the function `NSEvent::pressedMouseButtons()`.